# PyQt5 possible to use QWebEngineView to print PDF in background, no GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to use Python to convert some html files to PDF.
After looking at the modules and possibilities to do this, I settled on Qt5.

I have code that works, but it doesn't work exactly how I want.
I want to run my program via the command line, and it to exit once finished.
Currently, it produces the PDF but stays running.

If I uncomment and show the QWebEngineView with view.show(), then I can close the window that opens and the program will exit. (But I don't want to have any GUI, so this isn't good)

Next, I tried to show the view, then immediately close it after with view.close(), but when I do this a PDF doesn't get generated. I tried adding a 5 second sleep after view.show() and before view.close(), but still the same result.

I'm not sure if what I want is possible, I understand Qt is for GUIs but it would be very convenient if I could get this working completely through the command line.

```
import sys
import os
from time import sleep

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, QUrl

# needed to load local html files
sys.argv.append("--disable-web-security")
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

raw_html = ""
with open('webpage.htm', 'r') as myfile:
    raw_html = myfile.read()

view = QWebEngineView()
view.setHtml(raw_html)

def save_pdf(finished):
    view.page().printToPdf("output.pdf")
    # view.show()
    # view.close()

view.loadFinished.connect(save_pdf)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is your pyqt version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
loader.setZoomFactor(1)

loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(loader.close)             # <---

loader.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'))

def emit_pdf(finished):
    #loader.show()
    loader.page().printToPdf("test.pdf")

loader.loadFinished.connect(emit_pdf)

app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks, but: AttributeError: 'QWebEnginePage' object has no attribute 'pdfPrintingFinished'

Comment: @BenKailon update your pyqt5, the pdfPrintingFinished signal was recently implemented in Qt 5.9

Comment: @eyllanesc ah it was 5.8.1, I didn't even think about that. Sorry.

Now, after updating, I get a different error.

ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebEngineWidgets'

After a little research it looks like the 32 bit Windows PyQt5 wheels that pip installs don't have QtWebEngineWidgets anymore... This is getting complicated!

Comment: Just a win32 issue, but after downgrading pyqt5 to 5.10, it's working perfectly.
Thanks to both of you.